# Which ghosts were based on folklore?

Tags: harry-potter

On Accio Quote, the point is made that:

> JKR speaks of researching specific ghosts, **implying that one or more
>   of the Hogwarts ghosts are based on ghosts from folklore.**

Do we know whether any individual ghosts actually *were* based on folklore.  If so, **who were the ghosts and whom were they based on?**

To clarify, I'm looking for evidence from **JKR herself** which confirms that one or more of the ghosts was based on folklore and *who/what* in folklore they were based on.

Comment: Tempted to flag this as too broad and/or opinion based. Nearly Headless Nick reminds me of the Headless Rider of Sleepy Hollow...

Comment: @Thomas I see your point and have modified the question accordingly to make it less opinion based and, hopefully, less broad as well

Comment: much better and an interesting question +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Grey Lady

Finding a statement from J.K. Rowling concerning which *specific* ghosts she researched has proved challenging.

However, one ghost that is almost certainly inspired by folklore is **"The Grey Lady"** of Ravenclaw.

Historically, a ghost by the name of "The Grey Lady" has been purported to haunt Rufford Old Hall in Lancashire, England, and another ghost of the same name has been thought to haunt Scotland's Glamis Castle.

Here is a [book excerpt](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RoKoAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT93&lpg=PT93&dq=grey+lady+ghost+lancashire&source=bl&ots=T1PWHWKumr&sig=AAgJzx26jj1rGJCO3GHV95BKq7Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwiKkfethsjHAhUJV5IKHd2LCE8#v=onepage&q=grey%20lady%20ghost%20lancashire&f=false) concerning "The Grey Lady" of Rufford Old Hall — the legend dates back to the 1580s.

Outside the UK, the folklore of Malta also tells of a "Grey Lady" ghost.

Incidentally, these "Grey Lady" ghost tales also inspired the infamous "Grey Lady" poltergeist from the first *Ghostbusters* film.

Comment: I myself must be possessed by a ghost, for I have done the unthinkable: I answered a Harry Potter question.